# Motorola Droid Razr Maxx HD HDMI Portrait Mode

Tags: lock-screens, screen, motorola-droid-razr, hdmi, orientation

I have Razr Maxx HD with a broken screen and partially functioning digitizer. I am attempting some data recovery. I have an HDMI cable and monitor, and I have a USB OTG hub on order (for mouse control) but it has not arrived yet. I'd like to do this ASAP and not have to wait for the hub to arrive.

It is stock, no root. USB debugging is not enabled.

The HDMI out is working fine. The problem is, it seems to always display in landscape mode, and I can't enter my unlock pattern because that portion of the digitizer is unresponsive.

Can I make it display the unlock screen in portrait mode? I noticed when I press the power button to turn the display off then press it again to turn it back on, for a brief moment it displays portrait mode on the monitor but immediately rotates. So, obviously, the capability of rendering portrait mode over the HDMI output exists, I just don't know how to make it stay that way.

Comment: @Izzy Our discussion in these comments is around the answer you made in your first comment (which you have mysteriously deleted, thus confusing the context even more), which was indirect and doesn't involve HDMI and portrait mode. This question is about HDMI and portrait mode, not anything else. The info you added was completely off topic for my question. You certainly made a bit of a mess of this comment discussion. I will delete my comments now too, because they are no longer meaningful.

Comment: Sorry for that: I tried to address the underlying problem. Please, move the link from your first comment directly to the question (using the [edit] link), pointing out what you just wrote in your last comment (that you're explicitly after the HDMI problem, as alternatives are already addressed in the other question – so nobody runs into the same confusion as I did). Then let's remove all confusing comments for a "fresh start", as you suggested (and I did in my previous comment; unfortunately, you removed my summary from your question again as well; but of course it's yours ;)

Comment: I see no need to edit. I believe it's already clear that I'm explicitly after the hdmi problem because that's precisely the question I asked. Not sure if I can get much clearer than "can I display the unlock screen in portrait mode" in a question titled "hdmi portrait mode".